# How to print vowels from array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

Hey dear able to honor!

I'm writing a program of my assignment in which I'll need to show my full name and my I'd. using an array and also find vowels from my name and show them one by one in a column and also total numbers of vowels at the end. I did the first target and also done showing the total number of vowels, while I try too much to show vowels one by one with numbers like the following picture but I can't anyone can help so, please...

[This image shows how to print out vowels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjfh5.png)

if the Image is not open so image text is like something this:

```
My first name is: Bilal
MY I'd is: bc1234567890
last digit of i'd is: 0

vowel no 1 is: i
vowel no 2 is: a

Total vowels in my first name: 2
```

I tried this:

```
//for first name vowels
for(i1=0;i1<n1a[i1];i1++)
{
    switch(n1a[i1])
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        counter1++;
        break;
    }
    for(y=1;y<=counter1;y++)
    {
        cout<<"Vowel "<<y<<" is: "<<n1a[i1]<<endl;
    }
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Total Vowels Is/Are: "<<counter1<<endl;
```

Comment: `i1<n1a[i1]` is not a correct loop condition. It should be `n1a[i1] != '\0'` (to be verbose).

Comment: You also don't print vowels correctly. Instead you *count* vowels, and then print that many characters (disregarding if they are consonants or vowels) from the array. To fix your problem, you only need *one* loop, where you call  new `isvowel` function that you should create. If it returns "true" then you print the current character, otherwise you don't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following for loop

```
for(i1=0; n1a[i1] != '\0'; i1++)
```

Within the switch statement write

```
for(i1=0; n1a[i1] != '\0'; i1++)
{
    switch(n1a[i1])
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        counter1++;
        std::cout << "Vowel no " << counter1 << ": " << n1a[i1] << '\n';
        break;
    }
    //...
```

Or if the variable `n1a` has the type `std::string` then

```
for ( char c : n1a )
{
    switch( c )
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
        case 'U':
        case 'u':
        counter1++;
        std::cout << "Vowel no " << counter1 << ": " << c << '\n';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: sir, I try this but the result is not accurate I required print text like in the image but can't can I paste here whole code.

Comment: @Mehboob I do not see any difference with the output shown in the image.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your appreciation! I use another code that gives the correct output instead of my code that is :                    // loop while character is not null
for( i1 = 0; n1a[i1] != 0; i1++ )
{
    char upcase = toupper( n1a[i1] );
    switch( upcase )
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            ++counter1;
            cout << "Vowel no. "<< counter1 <<" is: " << n1a[i1] << endl;
            break;
    }
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Total Vowels Is/Are: "<< counter1 << endl;

Comment: @Mehboob From your question it is unclear whether you need to consider upper and lower case vowels as separate vowels or not.

Comment: Sir, I'm a beginner in programming. Please don't mind, I write my name only in uppercase letters if I write my name in both(like "Mehboob Shaukat") or lower case letters so how to manage this situation